# Django for tag doesn't work without a model

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to use a for bucle in Django but with my own list (not using de model):

This works great:

```
{% for book in book_list %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
{% for book in ['Lord of the rings', 'Django for Beginners', 'Harry Potter'] %}
    {{ book }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the array list from Django views. You can't just declare a list in templates. Templates are only for the front-end. First, declare the list in Django view and pass it to the template then display the data using for loop.

In Django views do this

```
def index(request):
my_book_list = ['Lord of the rings', 'Django for Beginners', 'Harry Potter']
return render(request, 'index.html', {'my_book_list': my_book_list})
```

In Templates

```
{% for book in my_book_list %}
  {{ book }}
{% endfor %}
```